# Declaring array but it shows an obj

Tags: typescript, angular7

I am declaring array in a component but the property is considered as object.
For Example

```
public searchFiters: number[];
```

the `searchfilter` is considered as `{}`

Comment: Please provide more code, so we have a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: 1. Where are you seeing it that it is an object? 2. Where does it get assigned a value?

Comment: export class FilterComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

   fruits: string[] = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana']; 
}


if i use this.fruits.length i get errors like length is not a property of {}
because it is not considering my array as array rather takes it as object. thats really
strange.

Comment: i am using it within a component

Comment: did you defined any reference to `fruits` in your html code something like `#fruits`?

Comment: Please post the code formatted in your question and not in a comment

Comment: i got it, it was just compile time error, it works fine now. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using it in a component, it's a good practice to give an initial value to the properties of your model, for example:

```
searchFilters: number[] = [];
```

But anyway, where are you accessing the property?
Please, provide more context and code to find a proper solution :)